# Unable to delete multiple rows in datatables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to show tables. There is a single button an on it's click i want to delete all the selected rows during that time. Below is my code.

```
var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );

$(anSelected).remove();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                "csv",
                "pdf",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        $(anSelected).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: According to documentation, you should do `TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'example' ).fnGetSelected()` to get the selected rows. (source: http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/api)

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: I solved it without data tables. Just using simple HTML tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code instead:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('example');
    var anSelected = oTT.fnGetSelected();
    $(anSelected).remove();
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v5t87o4/) for demonstration.